# D-ITG traffic generator Error on bind to receiver side Error at Receiver side

Tags: network-traffic, wireless

The architecture that is being tested consists of two devices placed in different location and connected between them by a wireless network.

The purpose is to send TCP or UDP traffic with D-ITG tool from one device to the other one trhough the wireless communication chanel. While I try to generate the traffic, I get the next error in the sender:

```
Error on bind to receiver side
Error at Receiver side
```

And the next error in the receiver:

```
Error into bind function!
```

The command in the source device is the following one

```
./ITGSend -a 10.0.0.5 -T TCP -C 100 -c 500 -t 20000 -x recv_log_file
```

The command in the receiver side is:

```
./ITGRecv
```

It has to be said that in localhost it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The receiver sees itself as one IP address but it gets another public IP from other networks. Just adding the option in the receiver side `-a IPwhichRcvSeesItself` solved the problem.